# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1.2:jar (default-jar)

Tags: java, maven, maven-jar-plugin

maven-jar-plugin fails with following error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1.2:jar (default-jar) on project myProject: You have to use a classifier to attach supplemental artifacts to the project instead of replacing them.

I am using java 11.
I upgraded maven-jar-plugin from 2.4 to 3.1.0.

It fails only on mvn clean install deploy. (without deploy it is running correctly).

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. `mvn clean install deploy` should be replaced with `mvn clean deploy` because deploy automatically runs install before. 2. I guess your `<phase>test-compile</phase>` should just be removed.

Comment: why should I remove <phase>test-compile</phase>?

Comment: `test-jar` has a standard phase, which should be `package`. Trying to run the goal too early in the lifecycle might cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I tried this, But it keeps fail

Comment: Then please add the whole POM to the question.

Comment: fixed by removing install and run only mvn clean deploy.

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061193/maven-generating-two-jar-files-when-used-with-classifier-tag/13061612#13061612 basicaly, use <id>default-jar</id> in execution

Answer (score 1):

This plugin doesn't like to create empty jars. Try the

```
<skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
```

setting for flexibility, particularly in large multi module projects when this plug is inherited into many modules.

Answer (score 0):

use this line in your pom:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

This helped me for java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a CI Pipeline with a project with multiple modules. What solved it was using

```bash
mvn deploy
```

instead of

```bash
mvn install deploy
```

The pipeline output in my case showed that the jar plugin was called twice, which is not allowed if pushing to a repository with a non-snapshot version.